# Access field is blank when value is not in combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has a field for "task performed" and a combo box of employee names to be picked from. The combo box links to a table with 3 fields:

- field1-autoid
- field2-employee_name
- field3-active(check box)

In order to keep the combo box list small and more user-friendly it only lists employees that are active (ie. employed). The problem with this is that when we scroll back through the records the inactive employees merely show up as a blank because they are not in the combo box.

Is it possible to get the field itself to still show the proper data but keep the combo box only listing active employees?

Comment: So your old records should have non-active employees in that field right?   Check to see if your combo box is set to "limit to list" and try selecting "no".  (I'm assuming that it's bound to employee_name in your design)

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.